# Is it Safe to Plug a Regular Power Strip (with no surge protection) into a Surge Protector Strip?

Tags: surge-protection

When I did a Google search I found a lot of different answers, many of which contradicted each other. My understanding is that you shouldn't plug a surge protector strip into a surge protector strip BUT IT IS OKAY to plug a power strip into a surge protector strip (if you don't exceed the max power rating for the surge protector strip)?

Answer (score 2):

End result: It makes no difference.
A "surge protector" circuit generally just shorts surge current to ground, so even daisy-chaining them (contrary to popular belief) generally has no ill effect.

More importantly, however, when daisy-chaining any form of extension cord, outlet expander, or power strip, it becomes very easy to overload the outlet, or one of the connections in/between devices, causing a breaker to trip, or creating an electrical fire!

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on where you live, the laws and the context. In most places, if a fire warden saw an extension cord or other surge protector plugged into a multi outlet strip (with or without surge protection) they would take action against you. The problem is you can easily exceed current ratings by doing that. Check your local fire code and\or national safety code to see what is acceptable.